# iPad UITableView top right corner covered with white box in landscape popover

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios7, landscape

I am attempting to create a custom popover for an iPad application in landscape orientation. I created a new UITableViewController with static cells on my storyboard and set the size setting to "free form". I then set the size of the UITableView to my desired size. I connected a Modal segue from the parent controller to the new popover.

Then in the parent UIViewController I created a method that performs the segue through a custom presenter. After working through a bug in Apple's orientation handling routines, I got the popover to show at the correct location.

When I run the app, I then discovered that in the top right hand corner of the UITableView a white box is displayed that covers whatever I place in the UITableViewCell. The more cells I place in the table the longer this white box appears.  So I believe it has something to do with the UITableViewCell not orienting properly although I have not figured out what yet.

I cannot seem to find what this box is, nor have I had any luck getting rid of it. Has anyone seen something like this?  Any help to get this white box remove (or whatever is needed to get the cells working correctly again), will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I was able to work around this problem.  It turns out that there is a bug in the modal segue logic that does not handle landscape orientation.  So I created a XIB and presented that as my modal view.  I still need to adjust things since it is landscape but the view displays correctly.

From what I understand this storyboard bug should be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Where did you read that there is a bug in the modal segue logic. I am experiencing the same problem where a white box shows on the top right corner for landscape view only

Comment: Actually I got the information from Apple. I used a support call.